# Playing a sound in c++ ... However, the game stops while sound being played ... how can I stop this lag?

Tags: c++, winapi

The sound is created using:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\hitBrick.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Comment: Try: "SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC" as last parameter.

Comment: How is it related to OpenGL?

Comment: @Michael: And OpenGL tag is gone :)

Comment: And the downvote is gone too ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As **Ville Krumlinde** already said, use SND_ASYNC like this:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("C:\hitBrick.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> SND_ASYNC The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns
>   immediately after beginning the sound. To terminate an asynchronously
>   played waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL.